# Mac OS X & MAMP - How to run mysql without having to type in the full path?

Tags: mysql, macos, startup

Right now, if I want to run mysql, I have to do /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u user -ppass... I'd be a happy camper if I could just do mysql -u user -ppass....  Been googling around, but haven't been able to find anything...  Have a feeling I'm using dumb search terms, so if anyone here knows how to do this, that'd be awesome...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can either add /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ to your bash  PATH variable (edit your .bash_profile, find the line with

```
export PATH=...
```

and add here the path to MAMP bin folder) , or maybe create an alias with

```
alias mysql='/Applications/.../bin/mysql'
```

(also in your .bash_profile).

Comment: Yes, this was it...sort of.......  I wound up adding the following lines to .bash_login

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"
alias mysql-start="sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql.server start"
alias mysql-stop="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql.server stop"

Comment: (Oh, and just in case anyone runs into this... I had to quit out of Terminal completely and relaunch it for it to take effect...)

Answer (score 5):

Add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/
```

to your ~/.profile

It will take effect next time your profile is initialized (I'm not sure when that is under OS X, it might be when you start your terminal application, it might be when you log in)

Answer (score 4):

It depends what shell you're using.  You should be able to add /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ to your path:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

Mac OS uses bash by default.  Just add this line to your .bashrc.

Answer (score 2):

Execute `. ./.profile` to restart your profile.